# How do I use `sorted` to sort a list of tuples?

Tags: python, sorting

Here is my list of tuples

```
[('Raven', '18'), ('Lion', '6'), ('Unassigned', '0'), ('Cobra', '6')]
```

I want to sort them by the value of the number in the tuple, to achieve this order.

```
[('Raven', '18'), ('Lion', '6'), ('Cobra', '6'), ('Unassigned', '0')]
```

How best is it to go about this, should I use `sorted()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sorted` takes a `key` parameter where you can specify on what basis you need the sort to happen:

```
lst = [('Raven', '18'), ('Lion', '6'), ('Unassigned', '0'), ('Cobra', '6')]

print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: -int(x[1])))
# or print(sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True))

# Outputs: [('Raven', '18'), ('Lion', '6'), ('Cobra', '6'), ('Unassigned', '0')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sorted`, with the following `key`:

```
sorted(t, key = lambda x: int(x[1]), reverse=True)
[('Raven', '18'), ('Lion', '6'), ('Cobra', '6'), ('Unassigned', '0')]
```

What `key` is doing here is to apply the defined `lambda` function to each element in the list prior to sorting. Consider the following equivalent using a list comprehension:

```
t = [int(x[1]) for x in t] 
# [18, 6, 0, 6]
```

And then it sorts the list of tuples using this `key`:

```
sorted(t, reverse=True)
[18, 6, 6, 0]
```

Comment: Are you sure that Lion and Cobra come out in the right order?

Comment: From what I understand it is only the numbers that are used to sort, nothing is mentioned with respect to taking anything else into account