# TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment On non tuple object

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, tuples

this code takes an **ordered** (highest score to lowest score) list of tuples and gathers the name and score of the highest, second highest and third highest scorers. If theirs a tie, both names are appended to the same list.

```
myresults=[('Raven', '18'), ('Cobra', '8'), ('Lion', '6'), ('Otter', '2')]


FirstScore=myresults[0][1]
SecondHighestScore=0
ThirdHighestScore=0
for i in myresults:
    if i[1]==FirstScore:
        FirstPlacePatrols.append(i[0])
for i in myresults:
    print(i[1])
    print(repr(i[1]))
    if int(i[1])<int(FirstScore):
        if int(i[1])>=SecondHighestScore:
            print(i[1])
            i[1]=SecondHighestScore
            SecondPlacePatrols.append(i[0])
for i in myresults:
    if int(i[1])<SecondHighestScore:
        if int(i[1])>=ThirdHighestScore:
            i[0]=ThirdHighestScore
            ThirdPlacePatrols.append(i[0])
print(FirstPlacePatrols)
print(FirstScore)
print(SecondPlacePatrols)
print(SecondHighestScore)
print(ThirdPlacePatrols)
print(ThirdHighestScore)
```

However,

```
i[1]=SecondHighestScore
```

Yields,

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Despite,

```
print(repr(i[1]))
```

Yielding,

```
'18'
```

Which is clearly not a tuple.

Comment: could you give us the variables we need to be able to run this code?

Comment: `i` is the tuple here. You cannot modify elements of tuple unlike a list; they are immutable. This seems to be a similar question, I've answered before. Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53989234/8472377

Comment: As the previous comment implies, `i[1]` is not a tuple but `i` is. Assigning to `i[1]` is an attempt to change the tuple `i`, which is not allowed.

Comment: Can you add some expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict
given_list = [('Raven', '18'), ('Cobra', '8'), ('Lion', '6'), ('Python', '6'),('Otter', '2')]
reversed_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key,value in given_list:
    reversed_dict[int(value)].append(key)

for k in reversed(sorted(reversed_dict)[-3:]):
     print(k,reversed_dict[k])
```

output:

```
18 ['Raven']
8 ['Cobra']
6 ['Lion', 'Python']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not change [tuple()s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuples) - they are immutable. You could create a new one. Or you could use `itertools.groupby` to group your tuples together and do some selective output:

```
myresults=[('Raven', '18'), ('Cobra', '8'), ('Lion', '6'), ('Swine', '6'), ('Otter', '2')]

from itertools import groupby

grped = groupby(myresults, lambda x: int(x[1])) 

# create a dict for all results
result_dict = {}
for key in grped :
    result_dict[key[0]] = [value for value,_ in key[1]] 

# print top 3 results:
for k in sorted(result_dict,reverse=True):
    print(k)
    print(result_dict[k])

# whole dict
print(result_dict)
```

Output:

```
18
['Raven']
8
['Cobra']
6
['Lion', 'Swine']

# whole dict
{18: ['Raven'], 8: ['Cobra'], 6: ['Lion', 'Swine'], 2: ['Otter']}
```

---

Second wayy to solve that by using a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
myresults=[('Raven', '18'), ('Cobra', '8'), ('Lion', '6'), ('Swine', '6'), ('Otter', '2')]

from collections import defaultdict

result_dict = defaultdict(list)

for value,key in myresults:
    result_dict[int(key)].append(value)

for k in sorted(result_dict,reverse=True):
    print(k)
    print(result_dict[k])

print(result_dict)


18
['Raven']
8
['Cobra']
6
['Lion', 'Swine']
2
['Otter']

# whole dict
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {18: ['Raven'], 8: ['Cobra'], 
                              6: ['Lion', 'Swine'], 2: ['Otter']})
```

Doku:

- [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
- [collections.defaultdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
- [sorted(iterable[,key=...])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)